# What do the __'s mean in this context?

Tags: php, magento

```
throw new Exception(__('exception'));
```

What do the __'s do? What are they called? I've seen this in several implementations and is common throughout the Magento codebase.

Thanks

Comment: As for what this is called, I like *"mmm mmm"*. *"So you just write 'echo mmm mmm open parens foobar close parens' to translate 'foobar'..."* ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`__` is a common name for a localization function. `__` is a valid function name like any other.

```
function __($text) {
    // return localized text
}
```

How exactly it works depends on the framework in question.

Comment: Look at `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract#__()` to see how the functionality is implemented in Magento.

Answer (score 3):

Usually if you see `__()` or `_()` its to pull the value of the string passed into the function from an i18n translation catalog. So the string passed to the function is looked up in the catalog and the appropriate translation is returned.